# How doesn't ng-click work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems there are many questions about why `ng-click` is not working

It seems straight forward, but it does not work:

```
<div class="span1 thumbCount" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div id="removeThumb" ng-click="delete()" style="margin-left: 30px;">
     <i class="icon-remove" style="color: #A2A251;"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

at the scope, I have:

```
scope.delete= function(){alert ("clicked!")};
```

but, `delete()` is never called

Comment: provide more of your controller code, including the part where you're injecting `scope` into it.

Comment: It must be `$scope.` instead of `scope.`

Comment: I found that there were a div over removeThumb div, which were preventing the event listening..

Answer (score 0):

As long as you specify that your page/view is using the angular controller where the delete method is defined, this code should work fine

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('BeerCounter', function($scope, $locale) {

  $scope.delete=function(){alert ("clicked!")};  

});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="BeerCounter">
<div >
  <div id="removeThumb"  ng-click="delete()">
     <i>ssss</i>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/fujujabayo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Check your console tab in browser for other script errors. If other part of your javascript is crashing, that would be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are some typos in your code. This one works fine. 
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="span1 thumbCount" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div id="removeThumb" ng-click="delete()" style="margin-left: 30px;">
       <i class="icon-remove" style="color: #A2A251;"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.delete = function(){
    alert("clicked!");
  }
}]);
```